# I am unable to increase size of this ASCII character shape in VGA text mode

Tags: assembly, emu8086, dosbox, vga

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 64    
.DATA


.CODE  
MAIN PROC  
    MOV AX, @DATA
    MOV DS, Ax  
   
   
    CALL SPACESHIP_SHOOTER
MAIN ENDP


   
SPACESHIP_SHOOTER PROC
   PUSH AX
   PUSH BX
   PUSH CX
   PUSH DX  
   
   MOV AH, 02H
   MOV DH, 24 ;Row Number
   MOV DL, 40 ;Column Number
   INT 10H

   MOV AH, 09H
   MOV AL, 127  ;Arrow shape
   MOV BL, 02H
   MOV CX, 1H
   INT 10H  
   
   POP DX
   POP CX
   POP BX
   POP AX
SPACESHIP_SHOOTER ENDP  


;==================================================
END MAIN
```

Comment: The problem is not in assembly language. Size and shape of characters displayed in text videomode is hardwired and fixed. If you don't want to be restricted, switch to [graphic mode](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int-10.htm) and you can design shapes of your own shooters and spaceships.

Comment: Choose a text mode with less rows and columns or less resolution. Then the text gets larger. Or VGA supports to define your own characters in text mode, even in addition to the existing ones (so that there are 512). With your own shapes you can build a large shape from several smaller ones.